# JSON test server with regularly updating data

Tags: web-server, json, angularjs

I want to develop a proof of concept AngularJS Single Page App.

Does anyone know of a public server which will serve me some JSON data every item I query it, and **not always the same values, but changing every time I access it**?

I found [JSON place holder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), but that only returns static data :-(

---

[Update] I don't want to have to register, it must really be "public". I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292050/is-there-any-publically-accessible-json-data-source-to-test-with-real-world-data) on S.O, but all of the answers are static. I want to demonstrate data-binding by having the APP fetch new JSON data periodically & update the HTML page (maybe something like a pie chart or histogram, but even a grid/list would do).

Minimal coding required, I am trying to prove that HTML/Angular are supported correctly in a certain environment.

Comment: At least "hard borderline" to asking for a service instead of software, Mawg. Only thing keeping me from close-voting is lack of proficience in this specific area ("in dubio pro reo": it might be I've missed the part making it on-topic). If you make that clear, I'll immediately delete this comment of mine :)

Comment: Hmm, @Izzy, I don't see way to rephrase it. I think that you might be correct & that it is off-topic :-(  I don't fancy my chances on Programmers, though. Any suggestions, or should I delete the question? That would be NP. I can just code my own & load in onto my server (but then no one else will know about it in similar cases).

Comment: Mawg, if by "test server" you mean a program to be run on some server (e.g. self-hosted), that should be fine. But your question rather looks like you ask for a "hoster" ("Does anyone know of a public server"). "Is there a software I could install on my (or my provider's) server" should make it perfectly fine – if that's (part of) what you want.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, nope. I want the off-topic public server. I will let you read this, then I will close the question. code something myself & use localhost. Sorry, I wasn't thinking when I posted. The difference is `klein, aber fein`, but it is clear.

Comment: OK, agreed. I just didn't want to sound "grumpy" (oder "nörgelig" :)

Comment: @łIzzy No, no, no, that's fine. I do understand the distinction & I do not want to set a bad precedent & have others think that it is ok to post similar questions. So, I shall delete this & do it myself. It won't take long. +1 for the crab ;-)

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1407313/restful-api-using-java-where-i-can-find-sample-restful-api-services-for-testing/1407328#1407328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NumbersAPI](http://numbersapi.com) will return at least dozens of distinct JSON formatted responses for requests to this URI endpoint.  No registration required.

http://numbersapi.com/random/date?json

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1407313/restful-api-using-java-where-i-can-find-sample-restful-api-services-for-testing/1407328#1407328

Answer (score 1):

In the nice [The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) article, the author shows an example using the [Github API for getting users](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users).

The interesting part is that it can get fresh new data with a random offset:

```
var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
return 'https://api.github.com/users?since=' + randomOffset;
```

Thus, you can get some simple Json with a huge amount of fresh new information.

Other parts of the API, like commit list, can be interesting.

I guess the Stackoverflow / StackExchange API can be interesting to explore, too... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although I previously accepted an answer, I have now found something which I consider far superior to it.

[Mockaroo](http://mockaroo.com/) lets you generate up to 1,000 rows of realistic test data in CSV, JSON, SQL, and Excel formats. It has 89 predefined data types, plus conditional logic.

Check it out!