# Fast changing data feed for software demonstration (data)

Tags: gratis, xml, json

I'm looking for a

1. **Fast changing**
2. **Easy-to-deserialize** (xml or json)
3. **Well formatted**
4. **Free**

data feed (I was thinking about a REST API, but I welcome any suggestion) for demonstrating a Java software component.

I don't really care what the data is about (weather, finance, anything goes), the main criteria is, that it should change pretty fast (new stuff at least every 5-10 seconds), and the format of the data should be well defined, so a JAXB / Gson parser can handle it.

If you have ever used such an open API, then please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you will accept that it returns a different, random, value every item you ask, then a "fast changing source" would be the one that I accepted to my question [JSON test server with regularly updating data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/json-test-server-with-regularly-updating-data).

To quote the accepted answer:

> [NumbersAPI](http://numbersapi.com/) will return at least dozens of distinct JSON formatted
>   responses for requests to this URI endpoint. No registration required.
>
> http://numbersapi.com/random/date?json

The `date` option returns something like this:

```
{
 "text": "May 26th is the day in 1830 that the Indian Removal Act is passed by the U.S. Congress; it is signed into law by President Andrew Jackson two days later.",
 "year": 1830,
 "number": 147,
 "found": true,
 "type": "date"
}
```

There are other types of data available.

If you read my question, you will see another proposed answer involving GitHub user data, which I imagine changes quickly, as new users sign up. I am not sure if it is quick enough, though.

Personally, I was more than happy with NumbersAPI for testing porpoises.

Answer (score 0):

Although my previous answer was accepted, I have now found something which I consider to be far superior.

[Mockaroo](http://mockaroo.com/) lets you generate up to 1,000 rows of realistic test data in CSV, JSON, SQL, and Excel formats. It has 89 predefined data types, plus conditional logic.

Check it out!