# Where to find free live streaming data, any format?

Tags: data-analysis, data

My company wants to set up an environment so employees can play with the new streaming data tools, like Storm and Spark.  For this we would like to have Streaming data to feed to users.  We could fake the data, but we would much prefer to have real data.  In fact we would prefer to have a few types of live data.  The more data per second the better, to stress our system.

Can anyone recommend any sources of live data that are free for us to plug into and stream through our systems?  Internet traffic and packets would be the ideal best type, but anything that is well documented api and has lots of data would do.

Thanks.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185). If you're looking for data, our sister-site [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be worth checking with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my (barely on-topic) question [JSON test server with regularly updating data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/json-test-server-with-regularly-updating-data)

The [accepted answer](http://numbersapi.com/) works for me.

---

[Update] In fact, I found something which I consider to be far superior to the answer which I previously accepted.

[Mockaroo](http://mockaroo.com/) lets you generate up to 1,000 rows of realistic test data in CSV, JSON, SQL, and Excel formats. It has 89 predefined data types, plus conditional logic.

Check it out!