# HTTP Response Codes

Tags: gratis, windows-7, http

We have a device that cannot handle certain HTTP response codes correctly. While we have identified one of them now, I'd like to perform tests for other response codes.

Therefore I'm looking for

- an application or virtual appliance
- that is gratis or open source
- and provides defined URLs for different HTTP response codes
- ideally for HTTP and HTTPS
- has more configuration possibilities than http://httpstat.us/

  - multiple redirects (see example below)
  - customizable response content
  - perhaps act as a proxy to get dynamic content from somewhere else

If the answer is an application,

- it must work on Windows 7 SP1 x64 (and higher if possible)
- may require admin elevation

If the answer is a virtual appliance,

- it must be for VMWare (Workstation 10) or VirtualBox
- may require Ubuntu command line knowledge
- may be any other OS if it provides a configuration UI

Example:

- `www.example.com/http404.html` returns a HTTP 404 "not found" response code.
- `www.example.com/http307.html` returns a HTTP 307 "temporary redirect", redirecting to a page that returns HTTP 200 "OK".
- `www.example.com/http307-301.html` returns a HTTP 307 "temporary redirect", redirecting to a page that returns HTTP 301 "moved permanently", redirecting to a HTTP 200 "OK".

Comment: Sorry, but your question, while interesting (+1), is not valid here, as we do not recommend web sites, only applications. Can you rephrase it to ask for an application? Please state the desired operating system and whether it should be free (use the "gratis" tag), or if you have a budget. Personally, I would code it myself, but I am very interested to see if there is a tool for this (which there almost certainly is)

Comment: @Mawg: ok, I'll do that after lunch. I have seen a few requests for web-services here before...

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of debate about that. There was an Area 51 site for web sites, but it never got off the ground.  Actually, even I am guilty of asking for web services :-)  See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/json-test-server-with-regularly-updating-data  I am certainly not going to downvote or request to close. I hope that you (we) get an answer and I would be happy enough with a web service

Comment: Hmmm, what about   http://webapps.stackexchange.com/  ?

Comment: @Mawg: Done. Edited to not be a web-service request.

Comment: I'd prefer [not coding it myself](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2353/9295)

Comment: I can post the code (just a few lines of PHP) and complete instructions, if you don't find anything else. Let's wait & see, but you can reply to this comment at any time * I will tell you how to do it. It's quite simple really

Answer (score 1):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will do all this.  It's not an out-of-the-box feature (which I doubt you would find in any product) but can be configured to do this.

Flow-chart policy with script items can be used to generate any response status code for a request, including response headers (there's basically a DOM for request and response (and other objects) rewriting).  You can alternatively divert requests to any local file (or CGI), or reverse or forward proxy.  If you want to generate content, you would probably need to run CGI (e.g. PHP), but all other aspects of a response can be configured in policy.

It has a free 10 user license which covers 10 concurrent connected users (IPs).

We also offer free support, even to free users, so we can help you get it working.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com)